# sqldf shows no rows in R when it is supposed otherwise

Tags: mysql, r

This query:

```
sqldf("select * from dataset2 where timeA='2016-11-29 08:00:00' or timeA='2016-11-29 09:00:00' or timeA='2016-11-29 10:00:00' or timeA='2016-11-29 11:00:00' or timeA='2016-11-29 12:00:00' and id<900000", method="dataset2")
```

produces this result:

```
[1] number       id           location     timearriving timeleaving  timeA        timeL        person      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

But instead it should give me some rows. Is the syntax of the query wrong or there is something else I didn't notice?

I also tried modifying the query by putting .000 at the end of timeA like this: *timeA='2016-11-29 08:00:00.000'* but its still the same result with no rows shown.

Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
number,id,location,timearriving,timeleaving,timeA,timeL,person
223248,124924,1002.18G,NULL,NULL,2016-11-28 08:00:00.000,2016-11-28 10:00:00.000,Student
223268,124425,SK-2.04,09:02:28,NULL,2016-11-28 09:00:00.000,2016-11-28 10:00:00.000,Student
223269,123366,SK-2.07,NULL,NULL,2016-11-28 10:00:00.000,2016-11-28 13:00:00.000,Student
223419,900234,1002.18G,07:57:13,09:50:41,2016-11-29 08:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Teacher
223419,124924,1002.18G,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 08:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223419,124510,1002.18G,08:06:54,NULL,2016-11-29 08:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223419,124509,1002.18G,08:06:52,NULL,2016-11-29 08:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223443,123398,101-01,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,2016-11-29 12:00:00.000,Student
223443,123375,101-01,09:59:01,NULL,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,2016-11-29 12:00:00.000,Student
223439,122904,1002.05,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 09:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223439,122903,1002.05,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 09:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223439,122887,1002.05,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 09:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223439,122875,1002.05,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 09:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223439,120742,1002.05,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 09:00:00.000,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,Student
223440,900213,1002.04,NULL,NULL,2016-11-29 10:00:00.000,2016-11-29 11:00:00.000,Teacher
224272,123324,SK-2.04,12:01:53,NULL,2016-12-06 12:00:00.000,2016-12-06 14:00:00.000,Student
224307,124345,101-05,NULL,NULL,2016-12-06 13:00:00.000,2016-12-06 14:00:00.000,Student
224307,124334,101-05,NULL,NULL,2016-12-06 13:00:00.000,2016-12-06 14:00:00.000,Student
224307,124321,101-05,13:04:34,NULL,2016-12-06 13:00:00.000,2016-12-06 14:00:00.000,Student
224307,124312,101-05,12:55:26,NULL,2016-12-06 13:00:00.000,2016-12-06
```

Comment: but in R it doesnt show that _.000_ , it is like _2016-11-29 10:00:00_. But still I did try to put .000 in my query but again it shows 0 rows

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: If you can check now please?

Comment: Look at `str(dataset2)`. I guess your "timeA" is `factor`. It should be `character`.

Comment: it says for _timeA_:

 .. ..$ timeA       :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ format: chr ""
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_datetime" "collector"

Comment: Could you try `timeA >= '2016-11-29 08:00:00' or timeA <= '2016-11-29 13:00:00'` in your query.  If the SQL is reading this as a datetime object it likely sees more than just the thousandth of the second, and can't resolve the equality.  If matching the exact time is important, you should probably separate the hours and minutes from the seconds.

Comment: That dataset was painful to read. Were all of those points necessary? Could a much smaller representative subset be used?

Comment: I tried that also Benjamin, it shows almost all of the rows in the dataset, and it should show only about 3400 rows, I can see this manually